# How to create Scrolling Effect like Grouek website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, computer-science

How can we create the vertical bar / spiral / splash kind of page animation effect found as we scroll down the web page at http://grouek.com/ website? I guess it is CSS3 or something advanced than it like Canvas. But is there any way to do it in CSS3 or jQuery?

Comment: Why not use your browser's dev tools to see how that site manages to combine umpteen different eye candy effects designed only to obscure the fact that there's virtually no content there? But hey, I'm not the target audience there, because I'm not impressed by shiny things.

Comment: What prevents you to inspect the source code of the said page?

Comment: I don't know why some questions on stackoverflow get so much hate. It's a legit question and he just uses an example page that he liked. It's not that he wants to clone this site or smth. Upvote +Favorite from me ;)

Comment: I had already used Firebug to inspect the source and I saw it uses canvas libraries. That's why I asked if there is any way to do it in CSS3 or jQuery :) It's a meaningful question I hope. Now i have the answer, thanks goes to ChinKang

Comment: I developed that scroll for the grouek website, It is handwritten canvas.

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-crop/

http://greensock.com/tweenlite

Cropping and tweening !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yea, to have such stunning effect we have to invest some efforts or money to get it. But since you tried to search but no hint, i will show you some starters :)

http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/

http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/

http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

there are a lot more libraries available out there, but it is alwasy fun to create ourselve ;P

Comment: Thank you so much :) I see http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/  will generate something similar, and it will be the prefect point for me to start developing this :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this would be to hire a professional web designer of the same calibre to recreate the multiple effects on this page. It won't be cheap. There's a lot of work involved, and its not a case of finding some script or piece of code on a site somewhere that will let you recreate this. This took hundreds of hours of someone's time to build.

Comment: I made that scroll for grouek website.
Effectively, is it handwritten in canvas and took a lot of hours to build it !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone :)
After some serious inspection, I see http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/  will generate something similar, and it will be the prefect point for me to start developing this :)